# Object Reference Not Set Error in SPImport.Run()

Tags: powershell, content-deployment, import, export

I'm trying to move my site from a server to another.

I exported my site using Export-SPWeb, moved the data to destination server and ran the function below: (Taken from [here](http://www.justaddcode.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/sharepointcmds.ps1).)

```
function import-spweb($sourceFile,$url,$retainObjectIdentity=$false,$includeSecurity=$true)
{
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment")
    $import = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport  
    $settings = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportSettings 
    $settings.FileLocation = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($sourceFile)
    $settings.BaseFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($sourceFile)
    $settings.SiteUrl = $url
    $settings.WebUrl = $url
    $settings.RetainObjectIdentity = $retainObjectIdentity

    if($includeSecurity){$settings.IncludeSecurity = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPIncludeSecurity]::All}
        else{$settings.IncludeSecurity = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPIncludeSecurity]::None}
    $settings.UpdateVersions = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPUpdateVersions]::Append
    $settings.UserInfoDateTime = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImportUserInfoDateTimeOption]::ImportAll      

    $import.Add_ProgressUpdated({write-Progress "Importing" ("Objects: " + $_.ObjectsProcessed )  -perc -1})
    $import.Settings = $settings
    $import.Run()   
}
```

Now, I did this before but somehow it doesn't work anymore and gives the error below:

Exception calling "Run" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I create destination site collection without a template by selecting "Select Later".

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered doing this using a DB-Attach approach instead?

If you are using SP2007 you have some stsadm commands at your disposal, in SP2010 there are similar cmdlets in PowerShell.

[Here](http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint/moving-my-sites-to-a-separate-web-application/) is a blog post where I extract my sites from an existing database and  merge them into another. TechNet samples on [stsadm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262923%28office.12%29.aspx) command.

On SP2010 there are also several approaches. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792.aspx) is an article on moving content databases using PowerShell.

Comment: +1 for the great post.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, using [this tool](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) solved my problem. I thought the program would be using the same methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the user running the script has permission on the database.

Verify that the same features are enabled at the source and destination site collection/site.

Comment: Yes the user I'm running the script with has full permission on the db and same features are enabled in both site.